# Pack binary data in php

Tags: php, pack

I need to send only 1 bytes of data and the output should be in binary integer
but the

```
pack("i",49);
```

outputs `31000000`

I need an output like this `31`

Please help.

Comment: "i" is a machine integer, usually 32 or 64 bits (4 or 8 bytes).  If you need to send only one byte, you should pack it with pack("c", 49);